# How to Animate Show / Hide Div with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to animate a show / div using javascript. The code works fine but i want it to open and close at 500 speed.

The code i have is this:

```
<a id="show-map" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Map</a>
<div id="top-map" style="display: none">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>

<script language="javascript"> 
function toggle() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("top-map"),
        text = document.getElementById("show-map");

    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show Map";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide Map";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on an example posted by keypaul [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7315/fade-in-and-fade-out-in-pure-javascript) I've adapted your code and shortened the example a bit for you:

```
<a id="show-map" href="javascript:toggle();">Show Map</a>
<div id="top-map" style="display: none">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>

<script language="javascript">
var ele = document.getElementById("top-map"),
    text = document.getElementById("show-map");

function setTime(state) {
    if (state === "out") {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout("fadeOut(" + (100 - i) + ")", i * 5);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout("fadeIn(" + (0 + i) + ")", i * 5);
        }
    }   
}

function fadeOut(opacity) {
    ele.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    if (opacity === 1) {
        ele.style.display = "none";
    }
}

function fadeIn(opacity) {
    ele.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    if (opacity === 1) {
        ele.style.display = "block";
    }
}

function toggle() {
    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        setTime("out");
        text.innerHTML = "Show Map";
    } else {
        setTime("in");
        text.innerHTML = "Hide Map";
    }
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use time functions like setInterval or requestAnimationFrame
here is an example of setInterval

```
//to fade out
fadeout_interval = setInterval(function(el){
    el.style.opacity -= 0.1;
    if(el.style.opacity<=0) clearInterval(fadeout_interval);
}, 30, ele);
```

alternatively you can use css to do the same thing